# RxJava 2 Maybe does not produce output

Tags: java, rx-java2

I have a single consumer and multiple producers - the records need to be batched before the consumer will attempt to execute some expensive operation.

Here is my attempt to implement the above using RxJava window and reduce functions:

```
import io.reactivex.Maybe;
import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.subjects.PublishSubject;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Rxtest {
  private PublishSubject<String> bus = PublishSubject.create();
  private Maybe<Observable<String>> maybe;

  public Rxtest() {
    maybe = bus
        .window(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 10)
        .reduce( (fObs, sObs) -> fObs.zipWith(sObs, (f, s) -> f + s));

    maybe.subscribe(obs -> obs.subscribe(System.out::println, Throwable::printStackTrace,
        () -> System.out.println("Done here")));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Rxtest test = new Rxtest();
    Stream.iterate(0, i -> i+1)
        .forEach(i -> {
          test.bus.onNext(String.valueOf(i));
          return;
        });
    Thread.sleep(100000L);
  }
}
```

The output I expected:

```
12345678910
11121314151617181920

....
....
Done here
```

Instead, I get nothing.

Comment: Other than the awkward setup, you have to complete the bus as `reduce` requires a finite sequence, which is clearly mentioned in [the JavaDocs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#reduce-io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction-)

Comment: Thanks. In my case, actually it is not finite. How do I change it to get the expected output?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to keep emitting items sometime after that IntRange or you don't know how to complete a bus?

Comment: I just edited the question to have a infinite stream. Hope that makes the intent clearer.

Answer (score 2):

The following will batch up 10 seconds worth of requests and process them.

```
observable
  .buffer( 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS )
  .subscribe( listOfString -> process( listOfString ) );
```

This will batch up 10 seconds or 100 items and process them:

```
observable
  .buffer( 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 100 )
  .subscribe( listOfString -> process( listOfString ) );
```

It is really not clear what you want if those two cases don't cover it.

Comment: Thanks! I missed that in the javadoc. Exactly what I wanted.